# Looking for design pattern suggestion for multiple hock-able conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

We are developing an HR ERP. We have "leave" module.

One of the basic features is **the request for time off or leave application submission.** We have a method for validating leave application for submission using almost 1000 lines of code. Lot's of `if, else and dynamic data conditions` are presents on this method. Point to be noted this method comes from the legacy system.

I am planning to use `Strategy pattern` to separate the business conditions and will refactor this 1000 line method into multiple small pieces of the method.

I request some experts advice on which design pattern are more appropriate in this scenario.

We are using Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC (.Net Framework dependent version.) with C#.

Comment: It is hard for experts to comment without first examining the code. I am not suggesting you post 1000 lines, but maybe after you analyse the code you might show how you intend to deploy Strategy. Then you have a better chance of a good reply.

Comment: There is not nearly enough data in your post to choose any design patterns. `lot's of if, else and dynamic data conditions` does not translate in any way to `singleton, strategy, and abstract factory`.

Comment: Seems like you are on right track with strategy pattern but template pattern my also come into play. Post some more info what is the ifs and other conditions statements about.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your valuable comments. To be honest, without code it's very hard to suggest the best solutions. Initially, I am planning to restructure the code using the strategy pattern. I may try to post some code snip sample for further improvement. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my limited context, a few thought immediately come to mind

The example below is in java, but you can translate to c#

1) if your input class/parent class is same, then you could have a list of validators through which you can run your input. The validators themselves will each validate a single factor and will execute in order of injection.  This is pretty much similar to the strategy pattern.

```
List<Validator> validators= {ValidatorA.class,ValidatorB.class,....};

public void foo(Input input){
for(Validator validator:validators){ // or use lambda
    validator.validate(input);
}
```

2) if your validation also has a lot of if/else situation where you would want to avoid calling some validations all together, the template pattern comes to mind. But template pattern is slightly hard to read/maintain (imo) so i would personally prefer the strategy pattern. But template patters does make more sense in some scenarios. So you could evaluate if it fits your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found a common suggestion for some of the experts as like yours. I am initially planning to apply the strategy. I will try to post some code snip for further improvement suggestions.